# How to proceed order on payment failure?

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2.3

We are using braintree.I want to know that how i proceed order on payment failure? we dont want to loose customer on payment failure thats why we want to store that order and we will contact customer later for their payment.
is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

As Braintree integration uses default flow, you can replace the implementation of `\Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder` for registered customers and `\Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder` for guest customers in your module via `di.xml` (re-define the `preference` to your implementation).

But, if you change the preference for mentioned interfaces, all payment integrations, which uses these interfaces, will start using your implementation. So, you need to be sure, that your implementation won't break the existing flow. And as a possible solution, you can decorate existing implementation (`\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder`, `\Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder`) and check received a payment code, if it's `braintree` - call your custom logic, otherwise - default implementation.